# How to return two columns (NoCond, Name) from Table 1 for those rows in Table 1 that do not exist in Table 2

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Problem when attempting to get the an additional column from Table 1 trying to return the 
NoCond and Name columns from table 1 missing in Table 2 for taable2.NoPro = AR102
SQL SERVER 2008

**Table 1**

```
NoCond  Cat     Name

001  G      INFORME JURIDICO
001  E      MANUAL OPERATIVO
002  G      ASIGNACION DE RECURSOS
002  E      CONSTITUCION DE LA UNIDAD EJECUTORA
003  G      PLAN DE CUENTAS
003  E      PLAN OPERATIVO
004  E      CONTRATACION AUDITORIA INDEPENDIENTE
004  G      PLAN DE EJECUCION
005  G      INFORME INICIAL
006  G      CONVENIO DE AUDITORIA
007  G      FIRMAS AUTORIZADAS
```

**Table 2**

```
NoPro   NoCond  Cat
AR101    002    G
AR101    005    G

AR102    003    G
AR102    006    G

AR103    001    G
AR103    005
```

**Expected Result** : (NoCon from Table 1 that don't exist in Table 2 for NoProj = AR102

```
NoCond Name
001    INFORME JURIDICO
002    ASIGNACION DE RECURSOS
004    PLAN DE EJECUCION
005    INFORME INICIAL
007    FIRMAS AUTORIZADAS
```

Tried the following Stored Procedure to get only the missing NoCond from Table 2

```
SELECT NoCondicion 
FROM   Condiciones AS T1
EXCEPT
SELECT NoCondicion 
FROM   ProyectosCondiciones AS T2 
WHERE  T2.NoProyecto = 'AR102' AND T2.Categoria = 'G'
```

The Results thrown are Correct

```
001
002
004
005
007
```

But when I also tried to get the Name column using this code:

```
SELECT NoCond, Name
FROM   Table1 AS T1
EXCEPT
SELECT NoCond, NULL 
FROM   Table2 AS T2 
WHERE  T2.NoPro = 'AR102' AND T2.Cat = 'G'
```

I´m getting the entire contents of Table 1 instead of those that do not exist in Table 2

```
001 INFORME JURIDICO
001 MANUAL OPERATIVO
002 ASIGNACION DE RECURSOS
002 CONSTITUCION DE LA UNIDAD EJECUTORA
003 PLAN DE CUENTAS
003 PLAN OPERATIVO
004 CONTRATACION AUDITORIA INDEPENDIENTE
004 PLAN DE EJECUCION
005 INFORME INICIAL
006 CONVENIO DE AUDITORIA
007 FIRMAS AUTORIZADAS
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear, but looks like you want a left anti-semi join. Please see [this article](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join) for more details on why I prefer a `NOT EXISTS` pattern over `EXCEPT`, `LEFT JOIN ... WHERE NULL`, etc.

```
SELECT T1.NoCondicion, T1.Name
  FROM dbo.Table1 AS T1
  WHERE T1.Categoria = 'G'
  AND NOT EXISTS
  (
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Table2 AS T2 
      WHERE T2.NoCondicion = T1.NoCondicion
        AND T2.NoProj = 'AR102'
        AND T2.Categoria = 'G'
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM <Table 1> t1
LEFT JOIN <Table 2> t2
    ON t1.NoCond = t2.NoCond
    AND t2.NoPro = 'AR102'
WHERE t2.NoCond is null
```

Comment: J Lo, your code throws the following results: 001 E MANUAL OPERATIVO
001 G INFORME JURIDICO
006 G CONVENIO DE AUDITORIA
007 G FIRMAS AUTORIZADAS